# Need to get chart series in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the series of a chart, rather than just the data range, since there can be ranges that have no series associated. I just have a single chart, so I know I can access it through `.getCharts()[0]`. Some options do return, but trying to return the series is just returning `null`. Here's my code:

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  let chart = ss.getCharts()[0];
  Logger.log(chart.getOptions().get('series'));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I am trying to get the series of a chart, rather than just the data range, since there can be ranges that have no series associated.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I get can the ranges with .getCharts()[0].getRanges(), but I need to actually get the series. So if I have a column for Jan/Feb/Mar, I want to check that the graph actually has all three series displayed, rather than just covering the data from the spreadsheet. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. Especially, I cannot understand about the difference between `the ranges with .getCharts()[0].getRanges()` and `the series`. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: The goal is to confirm, with Apps Script, which series are being used in a chart.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying of `The goal is to confirm, with Apps Script, which series are being used in a chart.`, I cannot still understand about the difference between the ranges with `.getCharts()[0].getRanges()` and `series` you want to retrieve. I apologize for this.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's ridiculous that nobody on the internet even know that the series may be different from data range. It looks like in the past they were always the same? There is simply no resource on the internet how to add series to match the data range